# Найти сумму целых положительных чисел, кратных 9 и от -30 до +40

Tags: python

Найти сумму целых положительных чисел, кратных 9 и от -30 до +40

Comment: Ищите - это не нам задание-то... будут КОНКРЕТНЫЕ вопросы по КОНКРЕТНЫМ участкам кода - вот тогда и спрашивайте.

Answer (score 1):

в довесок к @Victor VosMottor:

```
sum(i for i in range(-27, 41, 9))

sum(i for i in range(9, 41, 9))
```

и покороче:

```
sum(range(-27, 41, 9))

sum(range(9, 41, 9))
```

или немного индусского кода :)

```
from operator import add
from functools import reduce
print(reduce(add, range(9, 41, 9)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Буквально это задание будет выглядеть вот так:

```
sum(i for i in range(-30, 41) if i % 9 == 0 and i > 0)
```

Но по-моему это бред. По-моему надо так:

```
sum(i for i in range(41) if i % 9 == 0)
```